# uWSGI and Flask Server Sent Events

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, server-sent-events, raspberry-pi3

I want to run a Flask application on my Raspberry Pi 3. I already developed the Flask app and it works fine, but this is on Flask's development server.
I want to use a production server so i'm using nginx as the webserver and uWSGI as the application server on the Pi. Now, the Flask app uses server sent events (SSE) to to get live data from the server. When I run the app using uWSGI, it stalls. I believe its because i'm using SSE because I had a similar problem on the Flask server but all I did was enable threading and the problem was solved. Enabling threading on uWSGI (when running the uWSGI script) doesn't solve the issue though. HELP! 
This is my uWSGI .ini file.

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/pi/heap
app = app
module = %(app)
home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)
socket = /home/pi/heap/%n.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
callable = app
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it in port instead of socket mode with defined processes and threads.

```
[uwsgi]
base = project_path
chdir = project_path
module = your_module_name
callable = your_app_name
enable-threads = true
master = true
processes = 5
threads = 2
http = :5000
```

Comment: @joshuaramsamooj That's just a arbitrary number, you have to set it according to your server specs and site scalability.

Comment: @VivekR  but how should be the configuration in nginx? I can't use this with nginx, because nginx stalls

Comment: @chespinoza You can just proxy it in Nginx like `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000` and if you are using sockets then use `uwsgi_pass`.